# Joining two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Sorry if this is a super basic question but I've run into an issue while working on my R project. Basically I have two data frame objects, one which is a master list of genes and their level of expression in various patients and one which is only a single column in size. Then one with only a single column is a list of genes that fall under a specific subcategory of genes all of which are in the master list. I am trying to create a data frame where I have my specific subset of genes AND their expression across the different patients which is contained in the master list. I tried using the merge() function but only an empty dataframe was created.

Basically the code goes something like: new_dataframe <- merge(master_list, specific_gene_list, by = "gene"). I thought this code should look at my master list find all the genes in the specific list and then only take those genes and add the columns for patient expression, however my data frame is empty it creates a dataframe with all of the columns of the master list but no values filled in. Any help is greatly appreciated.

A visual example:

Master data frame

x: 1

y: 3

z : 4

w: 6

Specific data frame:

x

y

Desired data frame:

x: 1

y: 3

Comment: Hi cam21, please, could you provide some example data frame (ideally using `dput()`)? It'll be easier to help you as your "visual example" is not clear and we don't know if `x`, `y` are row names, column names or values... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can use `regex_inner_join` from `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
df3 <-  regex_inner_join(df1, df2, by = 'gene') %>% 
      transmute(gene = gene.x)
df3
#   gene
#1 x: 1
#2 y: 3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene = c("x: 1", "y: 3", "z: 4", "w: 6")),
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df2 <- structure(list(gene = c("x", "y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Still the same result as regular merge :(

Comment: @cam21 I updated with the results I am getting along with the data used.  It is showing the expected

Answer (score 0):

You could also split the column by the colon and add a new column to merge the dataframes.

```
mergecol <- c("x: 1",
"y: 3",
"z: 4",
"w: 6")

df <- cbind(mergecol, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(mergecol, ':'))))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c('x', 'y'))

mergedf <- merge(df, df2, by="V1")


result <- c('x: 1', 'y: 3')

assertthat::are_equal(result, mergedf$mergecol)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the columns in `master_list` using `separate`, join with `specific_gene_list` and again combine the columns with `unite`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

master_list %>%
  separate(gene, c('gene', 'value'), sep = ':\\s*') %>%
  inner_join(specific_gene_list, by = 'gene') %>%
  unite(gene, gene, value, sep = " : ")

#   gene
#1 x : 1
#2 y : 3
```